# Shell script to remove child xml tags conditionally

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, xml

I have a xml file having following content.

```
<contracts>
    <clients>
        <client>
            <name>Nicol</name>
            <clientRef>123</clientRef>
        </client>
        <client>
            <name>Basil</name>
            <clientRef>8234</clientRef>
        </client>
    </clients>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            <regCode>BCG</regCode>
            <clientRef>63352</clientRef>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <regCode>TYD</regCode>
            <clientRef>3242</clientRef>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</contracts>
```

The xml tags 'clientRef' are in both clients and entry sections. However, I need to remove the clientRef tags only in client section.

The desired output is :

```
<contracts>
    <clients>
        <client>
            <name>Nicol</name>
        </client>
        <client>
            <name>Basil</name>
        </client>
    </clients>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            <regCode>BCG</regCode>
            <clientRef>63352</clientRef>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <regCode>TYD</regCode>
            <clientRef>3242</clientRef>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</contracts>
```

I am new to shell and sed commands. How I can remove the clientRef tags with shell scripts?

Answer (score 14):

Although possible, it is a [very, very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1081936) to attempt to parse XML or HTML with tools like `sed` that are based on regular expressions. That can work for simple cases but gets really hard to get right, [even for experts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/1081936), for even slightly more complex cases. So, use an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet` (should be installable from your operating system's repositories):

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -d '//client/clientRef' file.xml  
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<contracts>
  <clients>
    <client>
      <name>Nicol</name>
    </client>
    <client>
      <name>Basil</name>
    </client>
  </clients>
  <entries>
    <entry>
      <regCode>BCG</regCode>
      <clientRef>63352</clientRef>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <regCode>TYD</regCode>
      <clientRef>3242</clientRef>
    </entry>
  </entries>
</contracts>
```

The `ed` means "edit this file" and the `-d '//client/clientRef'` means "remove `clientRef` entries under `client`".

---

In this particular case, you can also use simple text-parsing tools, so I will include an example, but please don't do this for anything more complicated, and be aware that it is likely to break with even a minor change in the input data:

```
$ awk '{ 
        if(/<clients>/){a=1}
        else if(/<\/clients>/){a=0} 
        if(/<clientRef>/ && a){ next}
       }1;' file.xml 
<contracts>
    <clients>
        <client>
            <name>Nicol</name>
        </client>
        <client>
            <name>Basil</name>
        </client>
    </clients>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            <regCode>BCG</regCode>
            <clientRef>63352</clientRef>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <regCode>TYD</regCode>
            <clientRef>3242</clientRef>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</contracts>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `xq` XML parser (part of [`yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/)), which is a wrapper around `jq` (so it's doing XML/JSON trans-coding):

```
$ xq -x 'del(.contracts.clients.client[].clientRef)' file.xml
<contracts>
  <clients>
    <client>
      <name>Nicol</name>
    </client>
    <client>
      <name>Basil</name>
    </client>
  </clients>
  <entries>
    <entry>
      <regCode>BCG</regCode>
      <clientRef>63352</clientRef>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <regCode>TYD</regCode>
      <clientRef>3242</clientRef>
    </entry>
  </entries>
</contracts>
```